# Internet through VPN doesn't work in Ubuntu 12,10

Tags: 12.10, vpn

I installed Ubuntu 12.10 on my G580 Lenovo laptop. Not everything but most of the things work fine. Today I brought my laptop to university. Here everyone has a pptp VPN account to connect to internet. I can connect to my VPN account successfully and ping websites but I cannot open any webpage! also I can't download anything from software center. everything works fine in Windows and home WIFI internet works ok.
Thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a DNS issue. Open `/etc/resolv.conf` and add `nameserver 8.8.8.8` or the University DNS server.

Comment: Hi I did that but resolv.conf says it self that adding anything to it is for no use because it will be rewritten. I added DNS from windows "ipconfig /all" to vpn connection's additional dns but didn't help.